# how to pull age, gender, placement, device by day from facebook using python

Tags: python, pandas, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to pull age, gender, placement, and device by day from Facebook ads using python. So far, I only found about age and gender, not placement and device. Also, the code I am running got syntax error.

Below is my code:

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.adobjects.adset import AdSet
from facebookads.adobjects.targeting import Targeting
import pandas as pd

access_token = 'access token'
ad_account_id = 'act_123456789'
app_secret = '123456789'
app_id = '123456789'
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token, api_version = 'v15.0')
my_account = AdAccount('act_123456789')
campaigns = my_account.get_campaigns()
# Define the API parameters
fields = [
    'campaign_name',
    'adset_name',
    'ad_name',
    'attribution_setting',
    'reach',
    'impressions',
    'frequency',
    'spend',
    'clicks',
    'inline_link_clicks',
    'objective',
    'cpm',
    'date_start',
    'date_stop',
]
params = {
    'time_increment': {'1'},
    'filtering': [],
    'level': 'ad',
    'breakdowns': ['age', 'gender'],
    'date_preset': 'last_90d'
}

# Initialize the Facebook Ads API client
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token, api_version='v15.0')

# Retrieve insights for the ad account
ads_insights = AdAccount(ad_account_id).get_insights(fields=fields, params=params)

# Convert the results to a Pandas DataFrame
fb_ad = pd.DataFrame(ads_insights)

# Print the DataFrame
print(fb_ad)
```

error I got is below:

```
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\facebookads\adobjects\adset.py", line 565
    def get_insights(self, fields=None, params=None, async=False, batch=None, pending=False):
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am new to API and didn't really understand the API document from Facebook. Any help would be much appreciated it, thanks.

Let me know if you have any questions, thanks.

Comment: `async` is a reserved keyword.  You can't use it as a variable name.  Choose some other name for your variable.

Comment: It seems that the syntax error is present in the package itself, though. What version of the package are you using?

Comment: `ads_insights = AdAccount(ad_account_id).get_insights(fields=fields, params=params, is_async=False)` or `is_async=True` depends on what you needed

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Good point.  Perhaps there is a newer version of the `facebookads` package that fixes this issue.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal @John Gordon, actually, the package is invalid for `from facebookads.adobjects.adset import AdSet`
`from facebookads.adobjects.targeting import Targeting`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is just simply removing the two packages.

```
from facebookads.adobjects.adset import AdSet
from facebookads.adobjects.targeting import Targeting
```

The rest of the packages still do the work.